# Which is preferred CTabCtrl vs. CPropertySheet in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc, cpropertysheet, ctabctrl

I don't know how to use both of them. So a sample code with pros and cons is perfect. Which one is preferred? Why?

Comment: Those controls are old as hell! Now there are more modern ones: `CMFCTabCtrl` and `CMFCPropertySheet`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Neither is preferred, they serve different purposes. If you want a dialog with several pages, use a CPropertySheet. If you need a dialog with several pages while part of the dialog remains fixed, use a CTabCtrl. A CTabCtrl can be used do everything a CPropertySheet can do, but since the CTabCtrl is more complex to use, it shouldn't be used unless you need its extra flexibility. A CPropertySheet can also be used as a wizard by setting a few flags.

The following is an example of using a CTabCtrl:

[aCTabCtrl Example http://rabien.com/image/xcolordialog1.png](http://rabien.com/image/xcolordialog1.png)

If this was a CPropertySheet, then it would not be possible to put the sample colors outside of the tabs. (And the buttons would have to be at the bottom)

[Tutorial on CPropertySheet](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/propertysheet/article.php/c605/)

[Tutorial on CTabCtrl](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/controls/tabcontrols/article.php/c5239)