# MFC: How to Identfy if Dialog was created using CPropertySheet or CTabCtrl

Tags: c++, mfc, cpropertysheet, ctabctrl

In reference to this question:[Which is prefered CTabCtrl vs CPropertySheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326079/which-is-preferred-ctabctrl-vs-cpropertsheet-in-mfc)

I have a DDK that uses MFC which I am new to. The basic example from the DDK implements a simple dialog box with 3 tabs with the "Ok" and "Cancel" button on the right side of the box.

Based on the question from the link above, seems like only CTabCtrl can have that kind of interface??**(correct me if i'm wrong)** However, looking at the classes involved, it seems like CTabCtrl is not used at all?? Need some explanation about this...

[image]

from Class Explorer:
**CObject-->**

- CCmdTarget

  - CWnd

    - CDialog

      - CxxxDlg
    - CPropertyPage

      - CIntHelpPropertyPage
      - CxxxConfigPage
  - CWinThread

    - CWinApp

      - CWinDebugApp

        - CDriverApp

          - CxxxApp

            - CDrvCfg
  - CxxxDrvCfg
- CSrvObj

  - CChannelObj
- CDriverObj

  - CxxxObj

Comment: http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2545/3858078115_c7d6b61f54_o.jpg

Comment: Odd question to ask you can find out certain info via RUNTIMECLASS but a property sheet uses a tab control as part of it.  Plus a property sheet and a tab control are handled in TOTALLY different ways ...

Comment: hahaha... this will sound stupid.. i'm just asking the question based on the link to another question... the answer to that question says that CPropertySheet  would have the "Ok" and "Cancel" button at the button of the dialog.. so looking at my dialog, the buttons are on the side... so i assume that it uses CTabCtrl.... but there is no trace of CTabCtrl being used in the project...

Comment: guess i'll just try out the examples in the link...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 classes derived from CPropertyPage, which is always used with CPropertySheet. No wonder there is no CTabCtrl. I'd like to explain in detail if you email me the code.

Comment: sorry for the late reply... just got back from a long weekend...
thanks so much for your offer to explain to me...
my e-mail address and IM is jjplawnewera@yahoo.co.uk.... could you drop me an e-mail so that i can contact you :)

Comment: hi boxoft... can i know your e-mail address?

Comment: Just send you an email from box # qiheng.biz. Hope to help you out.